# NPS policy for external firm?

Tags: wifi, radius, nps

Can NPS be used in the following scenario:

We (FIRM-A) are sharing some office space with another firm (FIRM-B). We would like their laptops to connect to our "Internet Only" SSID. Those laptops already have a working computer certificate for their NPS on their own network. Our NPS server would need to accept any request coming from a valid FIRM-B computer certificate. Our NPS server has a FIRM-B CA public certificate. Is this supported by NPS?